# Resize excel formula bar in power query

Tags: powerquery

I am playing around with the power query editor. While doing that I faced a strange issue. The power query editor does not show the formula (fx) icon and the formula bar is too small. Please take a look at below screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGIPR.png">

[image: <img formula bar]

I'm using MS Office 2010 SP2. Could you please help me fix this issue? Ideally this would involve resizing the formula bar and getting the icon in the formula bar (similar to the one excel has).

Answer (score 0):

This is an IE9-specific bug introduced in 2.24. A fix for it will be available soon. In the meantime you can use the Advanced Editor to edit formulas.